# Update each row with incremental value Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to update every row in a table in Postgres and set each row to a different value; this value is gonna be an incremental value with a start value.

For instance, suppose I have table `tab_a` with the following data:

```
|attr_a|attr_b|
|1     |null  |
|2     |null  |
|3     |null  |
|4     |null  |
```

The output I might want is:

```
|attr_a|attr_b|
|1     |5     |
|2     |6     |
|3     |7     |
|4     |8     |
```

Here is my script:

```
UPDATE tab_a
SET attr_b = gen.id
FROM generate_series(5,8) AS gen(id);
```

However is not working as expected...

Comment: update tab_a set attr_b = attr_a + 4;

Comment: @MightyRearranger attr_a is my id auto incremental, and not always will start with 1 like that, I just gave an example.

Comment: I'm guessing there are other fields in the table and you want the new values to be in a certain order.  If so then you can use 'Rank() Over (order by x, y, z) as RANKING' to get an integer value and use it to generate the series you want.

Answer (score 11):

You could do

```
UPDATE tab_a upd
SET attr_b = row_number + 4 -- or something like row_number + (select max(attr_a) from tab_a)
FROM (
  SELECT attr_a, row_number() over ()
  FROM tab_a
  ORDER BY 1
  ) a
WHERE upd.attr_a = a.attr_a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
UPDATE pr_conf_item upd
SET item_order = a.row_number
FROM (
       SELECT id, row_number() over ()
       FROM pr_conf_item
       ORDER BY 1
     ) a
WHERE upd.id = a.id;
```